# Como utilizar um arquivo Gulp para produção e desenvolvimento?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Estava pesquisando sobre como criar um arquivo Gulp que entenda como diferenciar quando for pra produção e quando for pra desenvolvimento. Achei o plugin abaixo, e gostaria de saber se essa é a maneira ideal de fazer essa diferenciação atualmente?

https://github.com/gunpowderlabs/gulp-environments

Nessa minha pesquisa, achei esse link abaixo, mas como foi criado em 2014, acredito que essa forma esteja desatualizada ou estou errado? É um pouco parecido com o plugin acima, porque cria dois endereços antes.

https://www.justinmccandless.com/post/a-tutorial-for-getting-started-with-gulp/

E se existe algum tratamento ou outro plugin que posso utilizar nessa dúvida?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri um jeito com o `gulp-util`:

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util

Depois de colocar o `const util = require('gulp-util')` no arquivo gulpfile.js. É possível criar uma task default com uma condição de produção para executar uma outra tarefa, caso você precise:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    if(util.env.prod){
        gulp.start('producao')
    } else {
        gulp.start('desenv')
    }
})
```

Depois disso, é só utilizar o comando do gulp no prompt para produção com o mesmo nome depois do `util.env.`:

```
gulp --prod
```